# Initialising nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm trying to learn more about templates and have come across a problem I can't seem to solve.  At the moment the class below works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int s>
class myArray{
public:
    T* data;
    inline T& operator[](const int i){return data[i];}
    myArray(){
        data=new T[s];
    }
    myArray(const myArray& other){
        data=new T[s];
        copy(other.data,other.data+s,data);
    }
    myArray& operator=(const myArray& other){
        data=new T[s];
        copy(other.data,other.data+s,data);
        return *this;
    }
    ~myArray(){delete [] data;}
};
```

If I use it:

```
myArray<myArray<myArray<int,10>,20>,30> a;
```

a is now 30x20x10 array that I can access with the normal array brackets e.g. a[5][5][5].  I wish to add a feature so that I could write:

```
myArray<myArray<myArray<int,10>,20>,30> a(10);
```

and initialise all of the entries to 10 for example.  I can't work out how to do this.  As I understand, each layer of myArray is constructed using the default constructor.  If I changed this to something like:

```
myArray(int n=0){
        data=new T[s]; 
        fill(data,data+s,n); //T might not be of type int so this could fail.
}
```

I think this should fail when data is not of type int (i.e. on any array on dimensions > 1), however it doesn't.  It works when the array is square, but if not then some of the entries aren't set to 10.  Does anyone have an idea how the standard vectors class achieves this?  Any help would be amazing.  Thanks!

Comment: Your assignment operator does not clear up the old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::vector uses placement new on memory blocks.  It constructs the data.after allocating the memory in a second line of code.

This technique would work for you as well.  Be careful with placement new as it requires you to call destructors manually as well.

Here is a half-assed route without placement new:

```
template<typename U>
explicit MyArray( U const& constructFromAnythingElse )
{
  AllocateSpace(N); // write this, just allocates space
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    Element(i) = T( constructFromAnythingElse );
  }
}
```

with placement new, you have to allocate the memory first, then construct in-place, and then remember to destroy each element at the end.

The above is half-assed compared to a placement new route, because we first construct each element, then build another one, and use `operator=` to overwrite it.

By making it a template constructor on an arbitrary type, we don't rely on multiple conversion to get multiple levels down into the array.  The naive version (where you take a T const&) doesn't work because to construct an array of arrays of arrays of T, the outermost one expects an array of arrays of T as an argument, which expects an array of T as an argument, which expects a T -- there are too many levels of user defined construction going on there.

With the above template constructor, the array of array of array of T accepts any type as a constructor.  As does the array of array of T, as does the array of T.  Finally, the T is passed in whatever you constructed the outermost array of array of array of T, and if it doesn't like it, you get a compiler error message that is nearly completely unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, try something like this:

```
 myArray()
 : data(new T[s]())      // value-initialization!
 {
 }

 myArray(T const & val)
 : data(new T[s])        // default-initialization suffices
 {
     std::fill(data, data + s, val);
 }
```

If you're into variadic templates, you might cook up something even more grotesque involving variadically filled initializer lists, but I think we've done enough learning for one week.

Note the fundamental flaw in using `new`: Either version requires that your class `T` can be instantiated in some "default" state, *and* that it be assignable, even though we never require the default state in the second version. That's why "real" libraries separate memory allocation and object construction, and you never see a `new` expression unless its the placement version.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that and it works when 'MyArrays' has 2 or fewer dimensions.  For larger arrays I get 'no matching function for call to ‘myArray<myArray<myArray<int, 3>, 3>, 3>::myArray(int)’'.  Here's my new code if anyone gets a chance to take a glance: [http://ideone.com/PxJgo6](http://ideone.com/PxJgo6)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make specialization for arrays containing other arrays. To do this you need some common implementation class to be used in general and specialized MyArray:

Common implementation (I made some fixes for you - see !!! comments):

```
template <class T, int s>
class myArrayImpl {
public:
    T* data;
    T& operator[](int i){return data[i];} //!!! const before int not needed
    const T& operator[](int i) const {return data[i];} //!!! was missing
    myArrayImpl(){
        data=new T[s]();
    }
    myArrayImpl(const myArrayImpl & other){
        data=new T[s];
        copy(other.data,other.data+s,data);
    }
    myArrayImpl& operator=(const myArrayImpl& other){
        T* olddata = data; // !!! need to store old data
        data=new T[s];
        copy(other.data,other.data+s,data);
        delete [] olddata; //!!! to delete it after copying
        return *this;
    }
    ~myArrayImpl(){delete [] data;}
};
```

Then make general implementation - note the definition of `value_type` and `setAll`:

```
template <class T, int s>
class myArray : private myArrayImpl<T,s> {
    typedef myArrayImpl<T,s> Impl;
public:
    using Impl::operator[];
    myArray() : Impl() {}
    typedef T value_type; // !!!
    explicit myArray(const value_type& value) {
       setAll(value);
    }
    void setAll(const value_type& value) {
       fill(this->data, this->data + s, value);
    }
};
```

And the specialized version for myArray of myArray - see also differences in `value_type` and `setAll`:

```
template <class T, int s1, int s2>
class myArray<myArray<T,s2>,s1> : private myArrayImpl<myArray<T,s2>,s1> {
    typedef myArrayImpl<myArray<T,s2>,s1> Impl;
public:
    using Impl::operator[];
    myArray() : Impl() {}
    typedef typename myArray<T,s2>::value_type value_type; // !!!
    explicit myArray(const value_type& value) {
       setAll(value);
    }
    void setAll(const value_type& value) {
       for_each(this->data, this->data + s1, [value](myArray<T,s2>& v) { v.setAll(value); });
    }
};
```

And usage:

```
int main() {
  myArray<myArray<myArray<int,7>,8>,9> a(7);
  std::cout << a[0][0][0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << a[8][7][6] << std::endl;
}
```

Full example here: http://ideone.com/0wdT9D

Comment: Why not template<typename U> explicit myArray( U const & u )?  Ie, accept any type, and get an error iff it cannot be used to construct the contents.  In effect, what we want to say is "anything that can be used to construct my contents is fair game for me" -- yours works just if your contents are myArrays.

Comment: @Yakk You are probably right - I did not check - but it seems reasonable... I just afraid it will be too general. Moreover - any type castable to value_type can be used in my solution - and this cast will be done only once - not for every cell in [multi]arrays.

Comment: That is a nice feature of your solution!  +1